# Is there any solution to $x^2 \equiv 53 \mod97$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

Is there any solution to $x^2 \equiv 53 \mod97$ ( or in other words: is 53 quadratic residue of 97 ).

It is possible to place any of $0,1,...,96$ in the congruence and check if any of them is a solution, but there is got to be any easier way, which i can not think of. Would like to get some help or hints, Thank you!

Comment: Well, there's quadratic reciprocity.  Or you could note that $\frac {97-1}2=48$ and try to compute $53^{48}\pmod {97}$.

Comment: Do you know about quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: Look up "quadratic reciprocity", or "Euler's criterion".

Comment: (Also, you would only need to check up to $43$, since e.g., $44\equiv -43\pmod{97}$, and $(-a)^2\equiv a^2$)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin oh, I didnt even think about it! pretty new to the world of quadratic residues, so dont judge me :))) Many thanks to every one who answered!

Answer (score 1):

$97$ is of the form $4n + 1$. Thus the quadratic residue in the 'prime clock' diagram is the same as a quadratic residue for $97 - 53 = 44$, which is $4 \times 11$. $4$ is a quadratic residue, and so is $11 = 37^2 = 1369 - 97 × 14$. Thus the answer is yes!
We have used a theorem which I will prove.
By Fermat's Little Theorem, if $p$ is prime

$$\begin{align}
k^2 - k \equiv  0 &{\bmod p} \\
k(k^{p -1} - 1) \equiv 0& {\bmod p} \\
k(k^{\frac{p-1}{2}} -1)(k^{\frac{p -1}{2}} + 1) \equiv 0& \bmod p.
\end{align} $$
Thus since $k^{p -1} = (k^2)^{\frac{p - 1}{2}} $, this is a quadratic residue. Now for $p = 4n + 1$

$$(p - k)^{\frac{4n}{2}}k^{\frac{4n}{2}} \equiv 1 \bmod p$$
but for $p = 4n - 1$:
$$(p - k)^{\frac{4n - 2}{2}}k^{\frac{4n - 2}{2}} \equiv -1 \bmod p$$